# Amazon ec2 reserve instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

We received the education credit (valid for 1 year) from Amazon to use, and just wondering if we can buy reserved instance (3years) using that credit?

Is there any way to reserve how much bandwidth we can use too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The AWS education credit looks like it's a general usage credit, so just think of it as taking the credit amount off your AWS services bill.  You can use it towards a reserved instance, but since the credit is only valid for 1 year, you may not recoup the full amount; for example, if your credit is $500 and you pay $300 up front for a reserved instance and then incur $100 of instance costs in the first year, you'll lost the remaining $100 from your education credit unless you use it for something else within the first year.

You can't reserve bandwidth on AWS, you just pay as you go.

Comment: It is possible that the credit can be applied to related storage costs (i.e. S3 and/or EBS), bandwidth usage, etc.